# Redux-Form multi-line Google Material UI TextField does not autosize after displaying

Tags: react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

My react-redux multi-line Google Material UI `TextField` is not properly sizing itself when form is loaded hidden.

See the behavior here: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-template-qe06o

[image]

Reported on GitHub here: https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/4627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hack to fix this is to trigger an event when the hidden form is toggled from `hidden={false}` to `hidden={true}`:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```